# Yacc- Struct as incomplete or unknown type

Tags: c, struct, yacc, parse-tree

Here is my top of yacc file.y

```
%code requires {

    struct Id {
        char *var;
    };

    struct Commds;

    struct Commd {
        struct Id lhs;
    };

    struct Commds {
        struct Commd commd;
        struct Commds *next;
    };    
}
```

I used this code in my `%union` to defined new types for parser.

```
%union {
    char *id;    
    long long integer;  
    struct Id Identifier;
    struct Commd Command;
    struct Commds *Commands;         
}
....
%type <Command> command
%type <Commands> commands
```

I have no problem in using it with `$$`-dollars attributes while parse tree is building up while evaluating tokens from my lexer. Unfortunately I would like to use my structures which are defined in the beginning of the file in other methods in `%{ codes %}` section. Unfortunately whenever I define function  like this:

```
void add(struct Commd cmd) {...};
```

I am getting an error: unknown type! I would be grateful for telling me how to make this structs visible to my entire parser.

Comment: There seems to be one closing brace too many in your block of struct definitions. You may want to look into that first.

Comment: checked it it is not the case. I think the problem is connected with y.tab.h

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you just insert a minimal example (less than 20 lines, if possible) which exhibits the problem?  (Just the code blocks would be ideal.)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs usually because you have your union, tokens and types:

```
%union {
    char *id;    
    long long integer;  
    struct Id Identifier;
    struct Commd Command;
    struct Commds *Commands;         
}
....
%type <Command> command
%type <Commands> commands
```

before C code in `{% %}` braces. You need to put this after `{% %}`. Basically you're saying that your terminal or non terminal has type `struct Commd`, but yacc doesn't know what `struct Commd` is because you included it underneath union code.

You didn't write whole code so I can only assume you've done this. If that is the case, this is your answer.